# parsing CSV in java with quotes

Tags: java, parsing, csv, quotes

I have a CSV that I am trying to parse in java.  I am parsing it in fine but I have some fields that are quoted.  Meaning that they have quotes in the field that are escaped by another set of quotes.  What would be the best way to parse fields like this in java?

Quoted field:

""This is a quoted field"",This is not a quoted field

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to use [CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/index.html) library for this common task.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use CSV library to do this.
There are several open-source CSV parser libraries available.

[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

[SuperCSV](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html)